# Permission problems with a fresh install of VMware Server on Funtoo Linux

Tags: virtualization, vmware-server

It's the first time I install VMware Server because I need to run a Windows 2008 Server over our current Funtoo linux server. There was no problem on the installation and the configuration, where I set the default user as vmware.

The problem is that I try to login to the VMware Infrastructure Web Access using https://server-ip:8333/ where a username and password is asked.

I tried my root username and password and it says "You do not have permissions to login to the server.", no way to login with root or vmware also...

I've tried with `<ACEDataUser>root</ACEDataUser>` and `<ACEDataUser>vmware</ACEDataUser>` restarting vmware once edited and nothing.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run again the config wizard (`vmware-config.pl`) and answer the questions about the user that will the admin for vmware. It has to be a **valid system user** (double check that you can login in to your system with it from ssh).